# Конструктор перемещения матрицы

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор

Помогите, нужно создать конструктор перемещения для динамической матрицы.  Не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
Matrix::Matrix(Matrix &&matrix):
m_rows(matrix.m_rows),
m_colls(matrix.m_colls)
{
  m_matrix = matrix.m_matrix;
  for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++){
    m_matrix[i] = matrix.m_matrix[i];
    matrix.m_matrix[i] = nullptr;
  }
  matrix.m_matrix = nullptr;    
}
```

Comment: Конструктор перемещения должен по сути переназначать указатели на внутреннее содержимое. Чтобы переназначить эти члены нужно видеть определение класса `Matrix`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конструктор может выглядеть следующим образом

```
Matrix::Matrix(Matrix &&matrix) 
   : m_rows( 0 ), m_colls( 0 ), m_matrix( nullptr )
{
    std::swap( m_rows, matrix.m_rows );
    std::swap( m_colls, matrix.m_colls );
    std::swap( m_matrix, matrix.m_matrix );
}
```

У вас может возникать проблема из-за неправильно определенного деструктора. Как я понимаю, в деструкторе, прежде чем удалять каждый из элементов массива, вы должны проверить, не равен ли указатель `m_matrix` `nullptr`. Например

```
if ( m_matrix )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++ ) delete [] m_matrix[i];
}

delete [] m_matrix;
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае вы сначала присваиваете указателю (подозреваю, что `m_matrix` это указатель) на матрицу текущего объекта указатель из копируемого, то есть далее в цикле в строке `m_matrix[i] = matrix.m_matrix[i];` вы присваиваете значение само себе, а в следующей строке обнуляете его, причем в обоих объектах.

Кроме того, во многих случаях, где копирующий конструктор должен выполнять глубокое копирование, стандартный перемещающий конструктор является пригодным, т.к. применяет функцию move к полям переносимого класса, поэтому, возможно и в вашей ситуации достаточно объявить его как `Matrix::Matrix(Matrix &&matrix) =default;`

Comment: Первая часть ответа верна, но вторая - нет. В данном случае дефолтный перемещающий конструктор просто тупо скопирует значение указателя `m_matrix`, что приведет к разделению эксклюзивного ресурса между двумя объектами  со всеми вытекающими. Как правило рукописный констуктор копирования требует и рукописного конструктора перемещения.

Comment: @AnT, перемещающий конструктор по умолчанию применяет к полям объекта `move`, а не копирует. При применении `move` объект-источник перестает быть валидным. [Про конструкторы по умолчанию](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290523/does-a-default-move-constructor-equals-to-a-member-wise-move-constructor).

Comment: Во-первых, "перестает быть валидным" - это концепция уровня пользователя. Это задача автора класса - обсепечить поддержание и распознание "невалидного" состояния после move. На уровне ядра языка же нет понятия какого-то детерминистского состояния "невалидного объекта". Если вы сделаете move из одного голого указателя в другой, исходный указатель никак не изменится и никаким магическим образом не станет "невалидным". Он просто скопируется и все.

Comment: Во-вторых, судя по всему, в данном случае полями объекта являются поля фундаментальных типов: указатель и два целых числа. Для фундаментальных типов операция move эквивалентна операции copy: они просто копируются и все. Они сам по себе никак не "перестают быть валидными". В данном случае defaulted move constructor будет просто прямым эквивалентом shallow copy constructor. Со всем вытекающими.

Comment: Вот если бы `m_matrix`  был стандартным smart pointer, то тогда надежда на работоспособность defaulted move constructor была бы. Но это, очевидно, не так.